# Adding An Activity To Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

This is my very first android app. I am trying to do something that should be relatively simple, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.project1.project1">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**login_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/loginSignup1Background"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="@string/login_title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="Login Icon"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_login_black" />

    <EditText
        style="@style/LoginSignUp1Input"
        android:hint="@string/hint_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        style="@style/LoginSignUp1Input"
        android:hint="@string/hint_pw"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        style="@style/ButtonOrange"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_login"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.project1.project1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnLogin:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

**What I want to happen is...** when the "Login" button is clicked I get the short duration message of "Login button clicked!".

**What is happening...** the app closes with the error "Unfortunately Project1  has stopped".

**What I have tried...**

Different code variations in the manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity">
</activity>
```

I appreciate any guidance I can get.

And before anyone comments... yes, I have spent a great deal of time searching StackOverflow and was not able to find a solution.

**EDIT:**

**Stack Trace**

```
04-13 17:50:54.162 22926-22926/com.project1.project1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-13 17:50:54.163 22926-22926/com.project1.project1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.project1.project1, PID: 22926
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnLogin'
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5205)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21162)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
04-13 17:55:54.278 22926-22926/com.project1.project1 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22926 SIG: 9
```

**Latest Crash Log**

```
04-13 18:47:19.845 30895-30895/com.project1.project1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-13 18:47:19.850 30895-30895/com.project1.project1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.project1.project1, PID: 30895
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnLogin'
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5205)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21162)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

Comment: add the stacktrace please

Comment: @samuuel Eminet How do I find that?

Comment: `alt + 6` -> logcat. It's at the bottom beside the `terminal`

Comment: where is your onCreate method?

Comment: @Kuya try my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for all the help, but in the end this is what worked for me...

STEP 1) Move this code from LoginActivity.java to MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnLogin:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

STEP 2) In LoginActivity.java, change

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

to

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

and add

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
}
```

Final LoginActivity.java file

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
    }
}
```

Now it works. :)

Answer (score 5):

Remove **`android:onClick="onClick"`** from your **`Button`** of **`login_layout.xml`**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        style="@style/ButtonOrange"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_login"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

> **EDIT**

make the below changes in your **`LoginActivity`**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button loginButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
        loginButton=findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.btnLogin:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Login button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to set first layout view by setContentView(R.layout.activity_login). For that use override method onCrerate(Bundle savedInstanceState).

Comment: Still the same crash

Comment: @Kuya share latest crash log with question

Comment: @Kuya make sure that **`android:onClick=""`** not in your main activity layout

Comment: If I remove `android:onClick` altogether or set it to empty there is no functionality whatsoever when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

you already set onClick method on button

```
<Button

        **android:onClick="onClick"**
      />
```

there is no need to  implements View.OnClickListener  in LoginActivity

Answer (score 2):

clear code for you man 
First use `**Oncreate()**` method and infalted your layout...

Like this  :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    }
```

Then use your xml fields inside (Button feild) :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

 // Your Button 
            Button button= (Button)findviewbyId(R.id.button);

// button clicking event 
       button.setOnClickListener(this);

 }
```

---

---

1. AND FINALLY USE THIS CODE FULLY

---

---

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

        // Button creation
        Button button=(Button)findviewbyId(R.id.button);

        // And set Clicking Event

           button.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.btnLogin:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Login button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement onCreate() to inflate yout layout

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
}
```

If you don't inflate your layout with setContentView(R.layout.login_layout) your activity doesn't know, where the Id "R.id.btnLogin" belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

You did not inflated your layout.You have to override your onCreate method by pressing ctrl+O.

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout)
 }
```

If you want onClick listeners either you define

```
 android:onClick="onClick"
```

in your layout.xml

and create  method like below

```
public void onClick(View view){
   Toast.makeText(this, "Login button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

or you implement View.listeners like you done in your code.
But you can't do both.

Comment: The app still crashes with the same stopped functioning message

Comment: Are you trying to open MainActivity or LoginActivity?

Comment: If you are trying to open LoginActivity directly. Remove your IntentFilter in MainActivity and add to LoginActity in  Manifest file.

Comment: There is a menu that takes me to the login page

Comment: Remove your andorid:OnClick in your btnLogin

Answer (score 0):

First of all use override method to create and set layout view. Either set click listener to button from activity or from layout. I am setting it from activity class.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
loginBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Tried this and removed android:onClick="onClick" from the layout... I get no functionality. When I put it back... I get the same crash results

Answer (score 0):

Just Do below Process:

1)Right, Click on app Package.
2)New-Activity-Empty Activity
3)Copy Your XML code to the activity_main.xml file.
4)Java code to MainActivity.java.

Answer (score -1):

You have declared in xml as `android:onClick="onClick"`.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View)

You are getting this exception since you have not defined the method.So declare a **method with a name "onClick"** in your activity.

Just **`remove @Override and implements View.OnClickListener`**

Try this,

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginactivity);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer and got "error: incompatible types: LoginActivity cannot be converted to OnClickListener" during the build

Comment: can you please change your activity code like my edited answer and check

Comment: @Kuya did you try adding oncreate()